# How to dynamically disable a submit button if the username is already chosen?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to dynamically disable the submit button using javascript if the username is already chosen. According to my logic my code should be working, but it doesn't. Can anyone spot my mistake? Or is this not the way to do it?

python:

```
@socketio.on("submit username")
def username_check(data):
    if User.query.filter_by(username=data).count() == 0:
        emit("username check", True, broadcast=True)
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {    

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // By default, submit button is disabled
    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

    // Enable button only if there is text in the input field
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#username').onkeyup = () => {
            socket.emit("submit username", document.querySelector('#username').value);
        };
    });

    socket.on('username check', data => {
        if (document.querySelector('#username').value.length > 0 && data === true)
            document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
        else
            document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
   <form action='register' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' placeholder='username'><br>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder='password'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='REGISTER' id='submit'>
  </form>
```

My code does seem to disable the submit button when no input is given, but not when an username already exists. Thanks in advance!

edit: I added

```
else: 

    emit("username check", False, broadcast=True)
```

And now it seems to be working. But when I type to fast it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work better?

Comment: console.log data before the if condition and check is it reaching there?

Comment: I added `else:
  emit("username check", False, broadcast=True) ` And now it seems to be working. But when I type to fast it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work better?

Comment: type to fast? i dont understand. The condition fits perfectly now, by returning false from data varible it will no disable the button

Answer (score 0):

The condition `data === true` is always false, because the type of `data` is not `Boolean` (strict comparation checks for type equality first). You should write:

```
if (document.querySelector('#username').value.length > 0 && data)
```

or use a loose equality ('=='):

```
if (document.querySelector('#username').value.length > 0 && data == true)
```

or even better to compare:

```
data.length != 0
```